# EditTexts and ListView Practice in android not working

Tags: android, android-intent, android-listview, android-arrayadapter

I have made a simple android app with 2 activity..in 1st 3 editTexts and 2 button "insert" and "cancel" are there and in the second activity its a listView.I want is that when insert button of ctivity1 is pressed the values entered in 3 of edittexts from 1st acitivity should go to 2nd activity and display in a simple listView...I have tried following code but its not working...Emulator shows "Unfortunately app stopped"..

**mainActivity.java**

```
package com.example.listdemo;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.R.id;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
Button b1,b2;
EditText e1,e2,e3;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        final EditText e1=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        final EditText e2=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText2);
        final EditText e3=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText3);


      //  final ArrayList<String> noteList = new ArrayList<String>();
        //final ArrayAdapter<String> aa;
        b1=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
        b2=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);
    b1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            String s1 = e1.getText().toString();
            String s2 = e1.getText().toString();
            String s3 = e1.getText().toString();

            Bundle b=new Bundle();
            b.putStringArray("key", new String[]{s1, s2,s3});
            Intent i=new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SecondActivity.class);
            i.putExtras(b);
            startActivity(i);

        }
    });
    b2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this,SecondActivity.class);
        startActivity(i);
        }
    });
    }

}
```

**secondactivity.java**

```
   package com.example.listdemo;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.sax.StartElementListener;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class SecondActivity extends Activity {
    ListView ls;
    Button bt;
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_second);

              ls=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.list1);

              Bundle b=this.getIntent().getExtras();
              String[] array=b.getStringArray("key");

              ls.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,array));



            bt.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View arg0) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Intent i =new Intent(SecondActivity.this,MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);
                }
            });
        }

    }
```

**seconActivity.xml**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="306dp" >
    </ListView>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Back"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**Logcat**

```
05-10 15:41:50.279: W/KeyCharacterMap(3629): No keyboard for id 0
05-10 15:41:50.279: W/KeyCharacterMap(3629): Using default keymap: /system/usr/keychars/qwerty.kcm.bin
05-10 15:41:58.657: D/AndroidRuntime(3629): Shutting down VM
05-10 15:41:58.667: W/dalvikvm(3629): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40015560)
05-10 15:41:58.688: E/AndroidRuntime(3629): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-10 15:41:58.688: E/AndroidRuntime(3629): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.listdemo/com.example.listdemo.SecondActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
05-10 15:41:58.688: E/AndroidRuntime(3629):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1647)
05-10 15:41:58.688: E/AndroidRuntime(3629):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
05-10 15:41:58.688: E/AndroidRuntime(3629):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
05-10 15:41:58.688: E/AndroidRuntime(3629):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
05-10 15:41:58.688: E/AndroidRuntime(3629):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-10 15:41:58.688: E/AndroidRuntime(3629):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
05-10 15:41:58.688: E/AndroidRuntime(3629):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
05-10 15:41:58.688: E/AndroidRuntime(3629):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-10 15:41:58.688: E/AndroidRuntime(3629):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
05-10 15:41:58.688: E/AndroidRuntime(3629):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
05-10 15:41:58.688: E/AndroidRuntime(3629):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
05-10 15:41:58.688: E/AndroidRuntime(3629):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-10 15:41:58.688: E/AndroidRuntime(3629): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
05-10 15:41:58.688: E/AndroidRuntime(3629):     at com.example.listdemo.SecondActivity.onCreate(SecondActivity.java:33)
05-10 15:41:58.688: E/AndroidRuntime(3629):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
05-10 15:41:58.688: E/AndroidRuntime(3629):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1611)
05-10 15:41:58.688: E/AndroidRuntime(3629):     ... 11 more
05-10 15:42:00.727: I/Process(3629): Sending signal. PID: 3629 SIG: 9
```

**manifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.listdemo"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.listdemo.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.listdemo.SecondActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_second" >
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: Please post your logcat trace

Comment: i have put Logcat trace...sir

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have not specified your button id.You just declared the button bt.you have to get the refernce of your button specifyed in second.xml.

In the error it is showing that nullpointer Exception is in line 33.
This is where you have written the code for button click.
Edit your code  and give refernce to button bt as below.

Button bt=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button Id).

Also in first activity edit like this.

```
        String s1 = e1.getText().toString();
        String s2 = e2.getText().toString();
        String s3 = e3.getText().toString();
```

I tried your code with button refernce.Its working fine.

Comment: @jigar: just add Button bt=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1) before bt.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {.It will work fine

Comment: I have already posted that in my answer.. check it once, just enquire him before posting answer

Answer (score 0):

**Edit:**

In your Xml change id of listview to `android:id="@android:id/list"` and in your Class get it like this

```
lv=(ListView)findViewById(android.R.id.list);
```

This will happen when you use ListActivity, because ListActivity should have the listview with id `android.R.id.list` Check here for reference [List Activity](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ListActivity.html)

---

Your button `Button bt` is `null` because you haven't get its reference in `onCreate()`

Try to get your Button like this

```
bt=(Button)findViewById(R.id.yourButtonid);
```

I guess this is your issue, please post logcat trace so that I will post answer according to it

Comment: I have made cahnges as ur sugession..but still not working...!sri..please help me....its my practical test for job..! it can save my lyf..!

Comment: @jigar Post your logcat trace here...So that I can help.. Edit your question and post red lines in your logcat window

Comment: @jigar Nope, please check my answer...once.. in which I have provided Edit

Comment: @jigar Have you set id attribute of listview to `android:id="@android:id/list"` in your `activity_second.xml`

Comment: @jigar Have you register your `SecondActivity` in your `AndroidManifest.xml`?

Comment: @jigar Are you getting the same exception? Please update your code only SecondActivity and its XML and if any other exceptio post here

Comment: k...wait...sir...sir in my emulator "ListDemo unfortunately stopeed" displaying when i press "insert" button of activity1..

Comment: @jigar What is line no 33 in your `SecondActivity`? I have you initialize your button as I have suggested earlier in  my answer `bt=(Button)findViewById(R.id.yourButtonid);` before setting onClick Listener

Answer (score 0):

Your SecondActivity is extends ListActivity, so you do not need to setContentView and the ListView could be reference to use  `getListView()`

Comment: `getListView()` will not also work because listview in xml should have the id `android:id="@android:id/list"`

Comment: Brother..I have removed "listactivity" and place "activity" still not working...:(

Comment: Could you put new logacat here?

Comment: @jigar Change the android:id of the ListView to @+id/listView1, same with that id you are trying to get in (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView1);

Comment: ya...sir...i have edited...but the problem still remaining...please help me sir....its my practicle xam for job,...it can save me..:(

Comment: @jigar then you must refresh your logcat~